# OpenCV Can't setImage on CascadeClassifier for use with runAt

Tags: c++, opencv

Using OpenCV, I need to use the runAt method of CascadeClassifier to scan specific sections of an image.

According to the documentation, I need to setImage before I am able to use this method.

After some research, I found some other questions suggesting that you need to make a class that inherits CascadeClassifier in order to use the setImage and runAt methods due to them being protected.

After trying this, I get a segmentation fault when I call setImage, and I can't seem to figure out the correct way to do this.

The detect_multi method calls the built in detectMultiScale which detects the correct number of faces, so I know the basic class is working. However, every way I try to setImage in order to use runAt, it crashes with the segmentation fault.

Any suggestions?

Here is my code:

```
class MyClassifier : public cv::CascadeClassifier {
public:
    MyClassifier() {}

    void set_image(cv::Mat &image) {
        setImage(image);
    }

    void load_classifier(std::string file) {
        load(file);
    }

    void detect_multi(cv::Mat &image) {
        std::vector<cv::Rect> faces;
        detectMultiScale(image, faces, 1.1, 2, 0| CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, cv::Size(30,30));
        printf("Number detected: %zu\n", faces.size());
    }
};


int main() {
    cv::Mat image = cv::imread("GT.jpg", CV_8UC1);
    MyClassifier face_cascade;
    face_cascade.load_classifier("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml");
    face_cascade.detect_multi(image);
    face_cascade.setImage(image);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's a better idea to apply detectMultiScale on seperate ROI's instead of your subclassing approach:

```
CascadeClassifier face_cascade(...);
Mat image = ...
Mat roi1 = image( Rect(20,20, 40,40 ) );
face_cascade.detect_multi( roi1, ... );

Mat roi2 = image( Rect(172,40, 40,40 ) );
face_cascade.detect_multi( roi2, ... );
```

Comment: I was hoping to use the runAt method because I have to do some parallelization. I figured using the multiDetect in this way creates too much overhead, but I will give it a look in case I can't solve my setImage and runAt issues.